# Getting multiple responses from JSON api

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to get multiple values from an API website in JSON. The data that I am trying to get is

```
"pets": [
{
"type": "BEE"
},
{
"type": "HORSE"
}
```

How do I print out both values "BEE" and "HORSE"? I have tried

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
cutename = input('Enter your profile name: ')
r = requests.get('https://api.slothpixel.me/api/skyblock/profile/{}/{}'.format(name, cutename))
JSONData = (r.json())
result = str(JSONData)

pets = information['pets']
allpets = []
for d in pets:
    allpet = d['type']
    allpets.append(allpet)
print(allpet)
```

But it does not work.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Why do you convert your data back to a `string`? Where does the variable `information` come from? It would appear you just need `pets = r.json()['pets']`.